# Replace function arguments multiple times?

Tags: replacement, syntax

I have a very large function `f[x_,y_,z_]` and it's too cumbersome to type it directly. So I wish to break the definition and use (`/.`) multiple times, as follows (indicatively):

```
f[x_, y_,z_] := (int1 + int2 + int3)/.rule1/.rule2;
rule1 = {int1 -> iint1, int2 -> iint2, int3 -> iint3};
rule2 = {iint1 -> 1*x, iint2 -> 2*y, iint3 -> 3*z};
```

But this does not work. When I try to evaluate `f[1,2,3]`, it does not perform the transformation `rule2` and gives me `f[1,2,3]=x + 2y + 3z` instead of the evaluated number value `1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 = 14`.

I think this is because `rule2`'s definition on line 3 does not come into the *scope* of my function declaration on line 1, so the `x` I write in rule2 is *not* the same `x_` I'm trying to relate to.

How do I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: This is a good reason to use a scoping construct like `Block[]` or `Module[]`. You can then do something like `f[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{int1, int2, int3, rule1, rule2}, int1 = (* stuff *); (*stuff *) (int1 + int2 + int3) /. rule1 /. rule2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) define `rule1` and `rule2` before `f`, and  (2) wrap the rhs of the definition with `Evaluate`  to suppress the `HoldAll` attribute of `SetDelayed`:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[(int1 + int2 + int3) /. rule1 /. rule2];
f[1, 2, 3]
```

> 14

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @QMrules, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.